# Extended Events Result sql_text is ignoring comments how to Allow Comments in sql_text

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to add our user id from application as comment to Query like this

```
Select EmpSalary, EmpAddress 
From Employee 
Where EMpId = 34; -- CUSTOMER ID 24";
```

The main intent is during capturing the data using Extended Events, I wanted to filter only the queries related having comments -- Customer Id 24 and there by ignoring same statements captured in Extended Events by other users whose Customer ID 25 or 26 or whatever.

But the problem I am facing is when I am appending the SQL statement like this from C#

```
Select EmpSalary, EmpAddress 
From Employee 
Where EMpId = 34;" + "-- CUSTOMER ID 24";
```

The result in Extended Extensions session is showing `SQL_Text` as

> ""Select EmpSalary, EmpAddress from Employee where EMpId = 34"

and not showing comments. Is there any way I can persist comments in `sql_text`?

Comment: IMHO this is a bad idea. I can't imagine that depending on some meta-meta data is the best available approach.

Comment: @ZorgoZ please help me understand why it looks bad? is it having any performance or security issue ?  Help me understand that

Comment: Because it is not part of the data model. If - for any reason -you will need to switch to any other kind of database server, there will be no support for such things. On the other hand yes, there might well be performance issues as you don't have any control over how this is handled, stored and retrieved. Of course, Extended Events has its scope: it is a troubleshooting tool.  If you start a session it should capture ADO.NET also. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/data-tracing

Comment: @ZorgoZ iam sorry your answer is not impressing as i think
Performance Issue with comments i dont think so 
Controlling over what? .... 
<br>
My Whole intent was to distinguish The Queries caused by one specific user so i am using comments on it 

if you really think there is some other way to get meta data and distinguish the queries of specific user whos login id is some thing coming from application rather than Database user id it will be helpful 

thank you

Comment: Ok. Got your point. So your intent is troubleshooting. Still, if you can modify the schema of the table and add a new int field, you are way ahead.

Comment: @ZorgoZ thanks you, the concept of my adding comment will be done as prefix all time after query is generated by program before hitting sql server  so its like Dynamically just before final SQL Query is built i am adding comment as Suffix

so help me with ur suggesion is it going to have any security issue or performance issue ?